# C# struct compile errors

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, struct

This is a homework, and we don't learn the structs in C# (and I am learn now). So I go to the msdn, but I don't find what my program's problem...
Yes, and I can't translate fully assigned to my native languange, and I don't understadn what the compiler thinks.

**UML of my homework:** (we must use it)
 Interface: IComparable

- +Numerator{get;}:long
- +Denominator{get;}:long
- +Rational(numerator:long, denominator:long)
- +GCD(a:long, b:long):long
- +Equals(r:Rationaol):bool
- ...

*And we mustn't implement another methods or params.*

I write this homework in Java with classes and that work correctly.

I have a big problem, I don't understand what mean the following erros:

Error   2   Backing field for automatically implemented property 'Rational.Rational.Denominator' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller. Consider calling the default constructor from a constructor initializer.

Error   3   Backing field for automatically implemented property 'Rational.Rational.Numerator' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller. Consider calling the default constructor from a constructor initializer.

Error   4   The 'this' object cannot be used before all of its fields are assigned to

my code:
       namespace Rational

```
{
    //       (Rational is underline)     here the 2 and 3 error
    public struct Rational : IComparable<Rational>
    {
        public long Numerator { get; set; }
        public long Denominator { get; set; }

        public Rational(long num, long den)
        {
             // and here (GCD is underline) the 4. error
            long simple = GCD(num, den);
            this.Numerator = num/simple;
            this.Denominator = den/simple;
        }

        public long GCD(long a, long b)
        {
            long c = Math.Abs(a);
            long d = Math.Abs(b);
            if (d == 0) return c;
            return GCD(d, c % d);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (Denominator==1)
            {
                return Numerator + "";
            }
            return Numerator+"/"+Denominator;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            bool result = false;
            if (obj is Rational)
            {
                Rational r = (Rational)obj;
                result = this.Equals(r);
            }
            return result;            
        }

        public bool Equals(Rational r)
        {
            if ((object)r ==null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return this.Denominator == r.Denominator && this.Numerator == r.Numerator;
        }

        public int CompareTo(Rational other)
        {
      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add a `this()` to your constructor, or replace the auto-properties by properties backed by a field.

```
 public Rational(long num, long den)
 {
         // and here (GCD is underline) the 4. error
        long simple = GCD(num, den);
        this.Numerator = num;
        this.Denominator = den;
 }
```

Here you access the instance method `GCD` before you assigned a value to the auto generated fields backing your properties.

You should make this method static.

Next you will get the same error again, this time because you access the auto property `Numerator`. You can fix that by keeping the auto properties and adding `:this()` to the constructor:

```
 public Rational(long num, long den)
   :this()
 {
```

That results in the fields being initialized to `0` before your own constructor code runs.

The alternative is switching to fields:

```
public struct Rational : IComparable<Rational>
{
    private long _numerator;
    private long _denominator;

    public long Numerator { get{return _numerator;}; set{_numerator=value;} }
    public long Denominator{ get{return denominator;}; set{_denominator=value;} }

    public Rational(long num, long den)
    {
         // and here (GCD is underline) the 4. error
        long simple = GCD(num, den);
        this._numerator = num;
        this._denominator = den;
    }
```

---

Apart from this your code has few more issues:

1) You're using a mutable struct. That's usually bad design. Remove the setter from your properties or make it private.

2) You don't override `GetHashCode()` to be consistent with `Equals` (or it's just not shown in your code excerpt)

3) I recommend implementing `IEquatable<Rational>`. You already implemented `Equals(Rational)`, so you don't need to add any additional methods.

4) Your code produces int overflows very easily. Consider using `BigInteger`s instead of `long`s.

5) Unless you normalize your rational (denominator >0 and dividing both by the GCD) you get mathematically equivalent rationals that don't compare as equal.

Comment: Yes, but this is the first time that I here about mutable structs :)

If I delete setter from properties, I got this problem: 
Property or indexe 'Rational....' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
And by the UML, I have to remove setter. But if I make it private (the setter ) it will be good :)

Comment: Just search for mutable struct and you will find plenty on that issue. The short version is that a mutable struct has strange semantics in some situations, which one would rather avoid. Properties with public setter are not *that* bad, but any mutating method is.

Comment: If you remove the setter you need to use my third code snippet, where I replaced the auto properties with fields. And then you need to assign to the fields, not properties in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I added my question the UML... you see, we must use long, equals, only one-one getter prop, comparable etc... The prof teach us to the wrong ways... Tomorrow I will rewrite my code with your advices, and tips. I will see for IEquatable and BigInteger

Comment: Waht is your adiver to how I normalize my rationals?

Comment: "Properties with setters are not that bad" as long as you only use the object in the scope you constructed it in. No they create no problems but try to pass it to a method or return from a getter/method and they are basically rendered useless

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Does the OP have any mutating methods?  I'm not seeing any, just public setters, which you said "aren't that bad".

Comment: @blaces By that I mean diving by the GCD and making sure that the denom is >0.

Comment: @RuneFS What I mean by setters not being *that* evil is that the compiler catches most broken code. With mutating methods it doesn't. There are a few issues, notably casting to `dynamic` that cause problems if you just have public setters. @Merlyn It doesn't have mutating methods, but even public setters on value types are considered bad style.

Comment: `obj.MyRational.Numerator = 0` no warnings/errors (with Mono at least) and the value of Numerator is not changed. (Well it's changed on a temporary object)

Comment: @Rune Does not compile for me if `MyRational` is a property or readonly field. Compiles and changes the value if `MyRational` is a normal field. Using the MS compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the default constructor for this to work:

```
public Rational(long num, long den) : this()
{
    // and here (GCD is underline) the 4. error
    long simple = GCD(num, den);
    this.Numerator = num;
    this.Denominator = den;
}
```

A bigger problem here is that you have a mutable struct. This is never a good idea. I would make it:

```
public long Numerator {get; private set;}
```

Comment: thank you, I attached the UML of my homework to my question. So I must write in this way... but thank you for the tips :)

Answer (score 0):

I notice in your constructor for `Rational` that you are calling GCD and storing the result in `simple`, but you don't use the result.

Comment: This should have been a comment

Answer (score 0):

Make your `GCD` function static.

It doesn't use any instance members, and because it's called before instance members are set, it can't.